# Why aren't these two anchor buttons appearing in the same line? It worked for my div buttons. (HTML and CSS)

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs that I've gotten to be in the same line with "display: flex", but I can't figure out why it's not working for my 2 anchors. I feel like there must be something pretty obvious that I'm missing.

```css
#controls {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#hud {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<div id="hud">
                <div id="hud-item">
                    <p class="hud-prefix">
                        Question
                    </p>
                    <h1 class="hud-main-text" id="questionCounter">
                        
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div id="hud-item">
                    <p class="hud-prefix">
                        Accuracy
                    </p>
                    <h1 class="hud-main-text" id="accuracy">
                        0%
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div id="hud-item">
                    <p class="hud-prefix">
                        Score
                    </p>
                    <h1 class="hud-main-text" id="score">
                        0
                    </h1>
                </div>
</div>
<a id="controls">
            <a id="quitgame" class="btn" href="/index.html" tabindex="5">← Quit Game</a>
            <a id="continue" class="btn" tabindex="6">Continue →</a>
</a>
```

Comment: They are in the same line, for me. Could you perhaps include a screenshot of your issue?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/32tDFLK here's a pic

Comment: You'll need to include more code. The result in the image is nothing alike to what's provided.

Comment: You can't have a Link inside a Link (`<a>` - Tag inside an `<a>`-Tag ) First change your HTML so that this is not the case anymore, maybe then the styles will work.